# EF Linq Join an Array to Table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following class:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lng { get; set; }
}
```

I create an array of those objects.

I then want to determine if any objects in my array matchs a row (lat and long) in a table :

```
location = db.Locations.Where(u => centers.Any(s => u.Lat.Equals(s.lat)) && 
                                   centers.Any(s => u.Lng.Equals(s.lng)))
                       .ToArray();
```

But I get this exception :

```
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `centers` class in a query. This is not a primitive type like `System.String`, `System.Int32` or `System.Boolean`. You will have to collect the `lat` and `lng` properties from the `centers` class into arrays or other `IEnumerable<string>`  implementations.

Something like:

```
var centerLatitudes = (from center in centers
                       select center.lat).toList();
var centerLongitudes = (from center in centers
                        select center.lng).toList();

var locations = 
    db.Locations.Where(loc => centerLatitudes.Any(clt => loc.Lat.Equals(clt.lat)) && 
                              centerLongitudes.Any(clt => loc.Lng.Equals(clt.lng)))
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Dabblernl...My centers object is already a array of coordinate objects so should I just do: var coor = centers.ToList() to make it enumerable?

Comment: @boblautenbach an array is an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` too. Is the code I wrote not working?

Comment: I tried this...but its not working...locations = db.Locations.Where(loc => centers.Any(clt => loc.Lat == clt.lat) &&
                                     centers.Any(clt => loc.Lng == clt.lng)).ToArray<Location>();

Comment: This was the final code that worked:     

var lats = centers.Select(x => x.lat).ToList();
var lngs = centers.Select(x => x.lng).ToList();

locations = db.Locations.Where(loc => lats.Any(y=> loc.Lat.StartsWith(y)) &&                                                 lngs.Any(z => loc.Lng.StartsWith(z))).ToArray();